# How to forecast values based on 3/5/7/10 etc. last observations (Excel)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, forecasting

I have two columns of observations: Date and Number of Registrations.

| Date | Registrations |
| --- | --- |
| 01-05-2020 | 7841772 |
| 02-05-2020 | 8101873 |
| 03-05-2020 | 8065389 |
| 04-05-2020 | 7127299 |
| ... | ... |
| 19-05-2020 | 7208950 |
| 20-05-2020 | 7117984 |
| 21-05-2020 | 7906914 |
| 22-05-2020 | *to forecast* |
| 23-05-2020 | *to forecast* |
| 24-05-2020 | *to forecast* |
| ... | ... |

My task is to forecast the number of registrations for the remaining days based on 3/5/7/10 last values. So the first time I have to pick values from May 19th till May 21st, the second time - from May 17th till May 21st and so on.

The problem is, that there is a cell with a fixed number of days I have to use. There is a dropdown list that should affect the forecast every time I change the value in it.

I've been struggling the whole day to adjust my forecast.linear() function so it takes into account these changes.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the question, you could use an OFFSET. It is a volatile function, so you would not want to use this if you have to implement it on many sheets and if there is a lot of data entry as it will make the worksheet slow.

If you put the dropdown in D1, and your dates are in A and values in B, then the formula in the forecast area would be:

```
=FORECAST.LINEAR(A23,OFFSET($B$22,0,0,-$D$1,1),OFFSET($A$22,0,0,-$D$1,1))
```

Where row 22 is the 21st of May as shown in your table above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Didn't know that I can pass values instead of cell ranges in forecast.linear().